# Dijkstra with heap, python- Can't find bug

Tags: python, heap, dijkstra

I have an undirected graph with roughly 200 nodes.
I can't seem to find my bug because I'm passing/failing tests that look pretty similar.

```
def dijkstra(starting_node):
    starting_node.set_sp(0)
    starting_node.set_path("")
    heap = []
    heapy.heapify(heap)
    heapy.heappush(heap, starting_node)

while True:
    try:
        node = heapy.heappop(heap)
        node.Explored = True
        for (neighbour, distance) in node.neighbours:
            if not neighbour.Explored:
                if node.shortest_path + distance < neighbour.shortest_path:
                    neighbour.set_sp(node.shortest_path + distance)
                    neighbour.set_path(node.path)
                    heapy.heappush(heap, neighbour)
    except IndexError:
        return
```

Comment: Your code is clearly incomplete, unless you are passing some tests with the code above (how?). I don't see any call to your dijkstra method, and your algorithm seems incomplete?

Please edit it and add the missing information.

Comment: Have you debugged through your code? What have you used? I see couple of issues that would come clearly through a simple debug there.

Comment: I didn't think that part was necessary it is [here](https://codeshare.io/G8nj9j) though. Also, I set the node as explored when it is popped from the heap.

Comment: Kindly mention them. I am using pycharm with it's debug tools. Debugging a graph alg. though is quite tricky. And again most of the tests pass. Actually only 4 out of 30 fail.

Comment: So with a little more debugging, I've traced the issue to the heap. `heappush` is not working as expected, that is it is not appropriately ordering the elements after pushing. When I call `heapify` after every insertion, it works as expected. Why might this be?